# Using Heredoc with multiple lines is not working

Tags: javascript, php, heredoc

I was testing a simple assignment of a variable using Heredoc, but when I try to echo it nothing shows up

```
<?php
$varable = <<<LINES
1st line
2nd line
LINES;
echo "<script>alert(\"$varable\")</script>";
?>
```

But when I try to run it with only 1 line, it works correctly:

```
<?php
$varable = <<<LINES
1st line
LINES;
echo "<script>alert(\"$varable\")</script>";
?>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not support multi-line strings when using single or double quotes. There will be an error in your browser's console... _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"_

Comment: The solution would be to use backticks, ie `alert(\`$varable\`)` or encode the newline, ie `echo '<script>alert(', json_encode($varable), ')</script>';`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!